# Wordpress woocommerce PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

En principio, me gustaría aclarar que mis conocimientos en programación son muy bajos, y de `php` se bastante poco. También agregar que me he estado ayudando con el plugin `elementor`.

¿Cómo puedo visualizar el título del producto en la parte de arriba?

He estado realizando una plantilla totalmente personalizada (para diferenciarme de lo default). Se me ocurre que tendría que llamar una función y lograr visualizarla, pero nose como realizarlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos por tomarse la molestia de leer esta inquietud.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Seria posible, para ello tienes dos formas, jQuery o php, con php seria algo así:

En functions.php

```
function product_custom_title(){
    $productTitle = get_the_title();
    echo $productTitle;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'product_custom_title', 10 );
```

En tus Css:

```
.product_title {display:none;}
```

Esto hace un echo del titulo del product actual y lo agrega antes de la información del producto mediante un hook, puedes consultar la guía visual de hooks [aqui](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/)

La otra forma seria con jQuery, usando insertBefore o apeendTo que permite mover del DOOM un elemento a otra posición, la primera mueve el elemento antes de otro elemento y el segundo mueve el elemento dentro del elemento seleccionado, seria algo así:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.product_title').appendTo('id o clase del lugar a donde quieres moverlo');
});
```

o

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.product_title').insertBefore('id o clase del lugar a donde quieres moverlo');
    });
```